# Convert list of lists to single dataframe with first column filled by first value (for each list) in R

Tags: r, list, data-binding

I have a list of lists, like so:

```
x <-list()
x[[1]] <- c('97', '342', '333')
x[[2]] <- c('97','555','556','742','888')
x[[3]] <- c ('100', '442', '443', '444', '445','446')
```

The first number in each list (97, 97, 100) refers to a node in a tree and the following numbers refer to traits associated with that node.

My goal is to create a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df= data.frame(node = c('97','97','97','97','97','97','100','100','100','100','100'),
               trait = c('342','333','555','556','742','888','442','443','444','445','446'))
```

where each trait has its corresponding node.

I think the first thing I need to do is convert the list of lists into a single dataframe. I've tried doing so using:

```
do.call(rbind,x)
```

but that repeats the values in x[[1]] and x[[2]] to match the length of x[[3]]. I've also tried using:

```
dt_list <- map(x, as.data.table)
dt <- rbindlist(dt_list, fill = TRUE, idcol = T)
```

Which I think gets me closer, but I'm still unsure of how to assign the first node value to the corresponding trait values. I know this is probably a simple task but it's stumping me today!

Comment: If there is an answer that solves your problem, please mark it as accepted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a data frame with the first value from the vector in column 'node' and the rest of the values in column 'trait'. This strategy can be applied to all entries in the list using the `map_df()` function from purrr package, giving the output you describe.

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

x %>%
  map_df(., function(vec) data.frame(node = vec[1],
                                     trait = vec[-1], 
                                     stringsAsFactors = F))
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try the code below

```
h <- sapply(x, `[`,1)
d <- lapply(x, `[`,-1)
df <- data.frame(node = rep(h,lengths(d)), trait = unlist(d))
```

such that

```
> df
   node trait
1    97   342
2    97   333
3    97   555
4    97   556
5    97   742
6    97   888
7   100   442
8   100   443
9   100   444
10  100   445
11  100   446
```

Answer (score 1):

An option with `base R` is

```
stack(setNames(lapply(x, `[`, -1), sapply(x, `[`, 1)))[2:1]
#   ind values
#1   97    342
#2   97    333
#3   97    555
#4   97    556
#5   97    742
#6   97    888
#7  100    442
#8  100    443
#9  100    444
#10 100    445
#11 100    446
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution

```
library(tidyverse)
library(purrr)
node <- map(x, ~rep(.x[1], length(.x)-1)) %>% flatten_chr()
trait <- map(x, ~.x[2:length(.x)]) %>% flatten_chr()

out <- tibble(node, trait)
  node  trait
  <chr> <chr>
 1 97    342  
 2 97    333  
 3 97    555  
 4 97    556  
 5 97    742  
 6 97    888  
 7 100   442  
 8 100   443  
 9 100   444  
10 100   445  
11 100   446
```